# DNA, molecular descriptors

Tags: phylogenetics, phylogeny, rdkit, matrix

Are there any programs (preferably command line tools) for calculating molecular descriptors of DNA? I am looking for something like Chemopy or RDKit but specifically for DNA.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would like to perform classification after all, so the more descriptors are the better for me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some details. Explain exactly what "descriptors" you are thinking of, tell us what the input to this program would be and also tell us what operating system you are using.

Comment: Hi @BalintBiro, thanks for your feedback and answering your own question. Could you kindly mark this as "accepted", it helps with site stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the right solution.
iFeatureOmega does exactly what I was looking for. Sequence based and has CLI.
https://ifeatureomega.erc.monash.edu/iFeature2/index.html
Additionally it supports protein, DNA/RNA and also small molecule inputs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer on iFeatureOmega, cool. Could you please mark the answer as "accepted"?